# Call to a member function find() on a non-object()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Having started with CakePHP 3.0 I find docummentation very confusing as by following the code snippets I have genertaed the following code:

```
    if($this->Auth->User('role') != 'Admin' ){
             $query = $users->find('all')
                ->where(['Users.group_id' => $this->Auth->User('group_id')]);
             $this->set('users', $this->paginate($query->all()));
    }else{
        $this->set('users', $this->paginate($this->Users));
    }
```

Which runs perfectly fine if user is an admin, howver if he is not, then the code breaks on this line: `$query = $users->find('all')`

The following message is being provided:

```
Call to a member function find() on a non-object
```

The code is run in `users controller`.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Please write $query = $this->Users->find('all')

Comment: I have tried that as well, but then I receive the following error: Error: Call to undefined method Cake\ORM\ResultSet::alias()

Comment: I hope you have already loaded user model

Comment: I have got it working by passing the `$query` to the paginate instead of `$query->all()`. But this is by no means what docummentation suggest.

Comment: If you would have read the *whole* section, you would have found this in the documentation, even the examples that show it. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#using-controller-paginate Check the bottom of that section. Many people have the terrible habit of using documentation like a copy and paste code collection. Read through a whole chapter / section *before* implementing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
if($this->Auth->User('role') != 'Admin' ){

    $options = [ 
            'conditions' => array(
                "Users.group_id" => $this->Auth->User('group_id')
            )];

         $query = $users->find('all', $options);


    $this->set('users', $this->paginate($query));
}else{
    $this->set('users', $this->paginate($this->Users));
}
```

I think your issue is that you are essentially calling 'find' incorrectly.

```
$query = $users->find('all') ->$options
```

(not your exact code, but essentially what you have done, to help compare to my solution) should be

```
$query = $users->find('all', $options)
```

with $options declared above.
This is a much cleaner way (in my opinion at least) of managing find options, an can be reused if needed once they are set to a variable.